# WCF and EntityFramework - using virtual ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I have a WCF-Service, which should return a User with a list of Tasks.
Here is the code of my operation:

```
//in the Interface IService
[OperationContract]
User getUser();


//in the Service
public User getNewUser()
{
    return new User();
}
```

And here my classes (just like that to make it short, they are in different files):

```
[Table("user", Schema = "public")]
public class User: ModelBase
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> TaskList { get; set; }
}

[Table("task", Schema = "public")]
public class Task: ModelBase
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My Problem: using the virtual ICollection gets me an error when i call the WCF-Method (in that case getNewUser, it does not matter if there is something in it). Removing the "virtual" if the ICollection makes the WCF-Operation working, but then the Users i get from the database don't have the Tasks in their list. How is the correct way to fix this?

Comment: "*gets me an error*" And the error is...?

Comment: it has no error code, it says error at receiving the message, Connection closed by host. After a lot of Google i found out that the Problem is caused by the -virtual- but this is needed by the entityframework.

Comment: No, the `virtual` is **not required** by EF. It's needed for so called lazy loading. You can always remove it and use eager loading (`Include`) instead.

Comment: i am new to EF :( is there an easy example for that?

Comment: I see. Here is IMO a good post which can shed some light :) - [Loading Related Entities with Entity Framework - A Beginner's Primer](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/788559/loading-related-entities-with-entity-framework-a-b)

Answer (score 0):

TL; DR answer : The problem comes from EF only. You should deactivate the Lazy Loading (through the configuration) and use Eager Loading instead : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

From my conclusions, when you use Lazy Loading, the navigation properties are never `null`. EF leaves marks (leave a breakpoint and explore your values to see it) so EF can load data on demand (outside the initial query) and WCF can't serialize these "marks" when it wants to send a response.

The easiest way of preventing that is to use eager loading. You could also set to `null` all unnecessary navigation properties before sending the response to the client, but it's not really recommended...